# Trying to have my program ask a question, provide an answer, and then ask a different question

Tags: python

I'm a total noob and a little slow on the uptake, I'm having trouble finishing this code:

```
def main():
    question = input('What is the capital of California?: ')
    print()
    answer = 'Sacramento'
    quiz(question, answer)

def quiz(que, ans):
    if ans.upper() == que.upper():
        print('That is correct! ')
    else:
        print(f'Sorry, the correct answer is {ans}.')

    main()
```

I'm trying to have this program ask a question, provide the answer (if user input is wrong), ask a different question, and do the same thing. I can't figure out how to ask another question after the first question is answered. I'm trying to call the function twice.

If anyone can help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is store the question and answer in a list and loop through it, then check user answer with answer for each question.

```
def main(QNA_list):
    for question, answer in QNA_list: # loop through each question and answer
        user_answer = input(question + " ")
        quiz(user_answer, answer)
        print()

def quiz(que, ans):
    if ans.upper() == que.upper():
        print('That is correct! ')
    else:
        print(f'Sorry, the correct answer is {ans}.')

# store the question and answer in a list
QNA_list = [("what is the answer of A", "a"), ("what is the answer of B", "B")]

main(QNA_list)
```

Gives Output

```
what is the answer of A a   
That is correct! 

what is the answer of B a    
Sorry, the correct answer is B.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a good start, but there are a few naming conventions I disagree with in your code, and your code-flow seems backwards (`quiz` calls `main` and not `main` calls `quiz`).

Try the following code:

```
#optional: to ask questions in a random order,
#it is easy to use numpy.random.shuffle on a list of question indices
#install via the command line: py -m pip install numpy

import numpy as np 

def full_quiz():

    quiz_key = [

        ('What is the capital of California?: ','Sacramento'),
        
        ('What is the capital of New York?: ','Albany'),

        ('What is the capital of Texas?: ','Austin'),

        ('How many feet are there in one mile?: ', '5280')

    ]
    

    #ask each question once in order,
    for prompt,key in quiz_key:
        ask_question(prompt,key)

    #or,

    #ask each question once in a random order
    indices = list(range(len(quiz_key)))
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
    for index in indices:
        prompt,key = quiz_key[index]
        ask_question(prompt,key)


def ask_question(prompt,key):

    response=input(prompt)
    if response.upper() == key.upper():
        print('That is correct! ')
    else:
        print(f'Sorry, the correct answer is {key}.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    full_quiz()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

##### code

```
import random


# Create q and a data.
data = {
    1: {
      'q': 'What is the capital of California? ',
      'a': 'Sacramento'
    },
    2: {
      'q': 'What is the capital of Colorado? ',
      'a': 'Denver'
    },
    3: {
      'q': 'What is the capital of Texas? ',
      'a': 'Austin'
    }
}


def quiz(qnum, ans):
    correct_ans = data[qnum]['a']
    if ans.upper() == correct_ans.upper():
        print('That is correct! ')
    else:
        print(f'Sorry, the correct answer is {correct_ans}.')


def main():
    while True:
        r = random.randint(1, 3)
        answer = input(data[r]['q'])
        quiz(r, answer)

        if answer == 'quit':
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

##### Output

```
What is the capital of California? kk
Sorry, the correct answer is Sacramento.
What is the capital of California? ddf
Sorry, the correct answer is Sacramento.
What is the capital of California? r3edfd
Sorry, the correct answer is Sacramento.
What is the capital of Colorado? quit
Sorry, the correct answer is Denver.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves it:

```
question_list = ['question1','question2']
answer_list = ['answer1','answer2']

def main():
    number = 1
    question = input(f'{question_list[0]}:')
    answer = answer_list[0]
    for qu in question_list[1::] :
        if question_list.index(qu) != len(question_list) :
            if  question != answer :
                print(f"wrong, {answer_list[number-1]} is the answer")
                question = input(f'{qu}:')
                answer = answer_list[number]
                number += 1
                if question == answer :
                    print('great that is correct')
                    break
            else :
                print('your answer is correct')
                break
        print('im out of question sorry')
        print('bye bye')

main()
```